# pass a changing parameter to thread constructor got messed up, turns out to pass the last updated one to the thread, how to solve this?

Tags: java, multithreading, parameters, constructor

```
Calendar cal = Util.getCalendar(-10); //get the cal instance of 10 minutes ago
Calendar curr = Util.getCalendar(0);
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
//pass the timestamp(cal) to thread
while (cal.before(curr)) {
     for (String param : arr.keySet()) {
         MetricMeta mm = arr.get(param);
         service.submit(new GetBizFile(cal, mm.getColo(), mm.getPool())); 
     }
     cal = Util.getCalendar(cal, 1);
}
```

The threads created are all with the same timestamp (last updated which is cure), how to solve this problem?

The code for `Util.getCalendar()`:

```
public static Calendar getCalendar(Calendar cal, int minute) {
      cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
      return cal;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the `Util` class is in this case?

Comment: Don't pass or return `Calendar`s, pass or return `Date`s using `cal.getTime()`

Comment: post the Util.getCalendar() code. It's just to get the Calendar instance of "minute" away

Answer (score 0):

You do not update your Calendar variable because it is only a value, it does not increment automatically. You need to get it again from the system the next time you need it.

```
Calendar cal = Util.getCalendar(-10); //get the cal instance of 10 minutes ago
Calendar curr = Util.getCalendar(0);
Calendar start = curr;
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
//pass the timestamp(cal) to thread
while (cal.before(curr)) {
     for (String param : arr.keySet()) {
         MetricMeta mm = arr.get(param);
         service.submit(new GetBizFile(cal, mm.getColo(), mm.getPool())); 
     }
//You need to update your cal value (
//and increment it by the time that had past from the last iteration
     cal += (Util.getCalendar(0) - start);
     start = Util.getCalendar(0);
}
```

Comment: It could be the fact that you use the same instance of 'cal' when you pass it to the new Thread? They all reference the same address in memory, so it will have the same value in every thread. You should create a new Calendar for each thread.